# php html file upload form validation error

Tags: php, html, forms, file, upload

Im having problems with form validation.  When I dont select a file for upload I still get an error that promts only png images valid.  I thought that if no file was selected the $_FILES array would be empty.

What am I doing wrong?

my html form excerpt for file upload looks like this:

```
<label for="file">Filename
<span class="small">Upload image</span>
</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

my php processing looks like this:

```
 $submitted_file = $_FILES['file'];

 if(isset($submitted_file)) {

    // verify the file PNG only
    $fileType = exif_imagetype($submitted_file["tmp_name"]);
    $allowed = array(IMAGETYPE_PNG);
    $max_filesize = 512000;

    if (!in_array($fileType, $allowed)) {
    $proceed = false;
    $arrErrors['submitted_file_ext'] = 'Please upload .png images only.';
    }
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES);` and see that even if you don't load a file, `$_FILES` array is still set.

Comment: You are looking at isset($submitted_file), which you set to equal $_FILES["file"].  So it is set even if it is null.  You should be checking to see if it is empty with the empty() function or something like if($submitted_file=="")

Comment: i did a var_dump and got array(5) { ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["type"]=> string(0) "" ["tmp_name"]=> string(0) "" ["error"]=> string(1) "4" ["size"]=> string(1) "0" }

Comment: If variable equals `null` - `isset` returns false, btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array that you are checking should have the field ["tmp_name"] as null if it is blank.  Try this code instead:

```
if(!empty($submitted_file["tmp_name"])) {
```

Comment: i tried not empty but that didnt work if(!empty($submitted_file)) {

Comment: thank you.  that worked. why did that fix it if you dont mind telling me.

Comment: The tmp_name is the temporary location of the uploaded file on the server.  If no file was uploaded, the value "tmp_name" will be blank.  So, the empty() command is looking to see if that value is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

The right way is to check `$_FILES['error']`

```
if ($_FILES['name']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    // file successfully uploaded
}
```

More info here https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php